# Custom transport controls in media element. IsFullWindow = true

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mediaelement

I am using mediaElement and IsFullWindow property is set to true.

I need to use some control buttons, but when is fullscreen mode active, my buttons (like play, pause, stop...) are hidden behind mediaElement.

Ok. I can use

> AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"

but I want my own controls.

Here is tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh986967.aspx
but it does not use IsFullWindow property.

I want reach something like this: (custom transport controls in fullscreen mode)

[image: custom controls]

(screenshot from nokia video trimmer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to lay out the page manually, which isn't that hard.

Starting with a landscape page, you can resize the `MediaElement` so that it takes up all of the page.

You are then free to show your own controls above the `MediaElement`.

However it looks like this will potentially have a battery/performance cost, as it means you won't be able to benefit from the "system level optimizations" that `IsFullWindow` would give you.

You might be able to toggle between this manual full window and the optimized `IsFullWindow` version, but I haven't tried to see what this looks like.

Comment: Not happy, but thnx you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use "system level optimization" in IsFullWindow, unlike how the quoted page in MSDN page shows (in the question), using StackPanel for transport controls and making MediaElement stretch to mimic fullscreen, use Popup for transport controls. Because Popups always stay on top of other windows, even MediaElement, they will appear even in fullscreen. Use 'HorizontalOffset' and 'VerticalOffset' property of the popup to move them relative to immediate parent. This is shown in sample at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/basic-media-playback-003619be.